# Managed packaged validation rule fails when package license gets expired

Tags: apex, managed-package, custom-field, validation-rule

We have a validation rule on account object inside our managed package which checks the validity of custom field (from the same managed package).

After installing this managed package, the above validation rule works fine until the package license gets expired. It shows the error

> Field [FieldId] is inaccessible

on account detail page on updating/deleting account record.

Any information about this will be helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have to delete any `Validation Rules` which reference those components. When I ran into this issue in the past, deactivation wasn't enough. The error persisted until I removed the offending rule entirely from the system.